# Configuring network on a fresh installed 18.04: RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Tags: networking, netplan

I tried to install a new Ubuntu Server, but after the installation when I want to configure the network it didn't work using the Interface file.
so i tried as per duplicate to set up the network with `netplan`but thqt fqils too.

netplan file:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 193.171.201.236/27
      gateway4: 193.171.201.225
      nameservers:
          search: [pro2future.at, pro2future.eu]
          addresses: [140.78.2.62, 140.78.3.62]
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I suspect that your ethernet interface is not `eth0`; verify: `ip addr show`

Comment: 2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether db:44:2b:19:d3:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 193.171.201.236/27 brd 193.171.201.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: @chili555 edited and voted to re-open.  Your call though...  **:-)**

Comment: This file strongly implies that Network Manager is running here. Is that true? `ps aux | grep etwork` If ir is running, make your changes there and not netplan. As you have confirmed that your ethernet interface is eth0, why did you specify enp3s0?? Please clarify.

Comment: i dont now; i normally set up the network in the interfaces file (etc/network/).. and i found the netplan option on my researches..

Comment: but it does also not work if i change it to eth0.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have already checkout out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

I have found it more friendly if you use 'renderer: NetworkManager'.  Place the following into /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [ 193.171.201.236/27 ]
      gateway4: 193.171.201.225
```

Build /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf something like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[device-enp3s0]
match-device=interface-name:enp3s0
ignore-carrier=true
managed=true

[device-other]
match-device=type:ethernet
managed=false
```

Try a simple configuration first, then use 'ifconfig -a' to verify the configuration worked.

After you change the above netplan configuration file, restart the network:

```
netplan apply
systemctl restart network-manager
```

You may need to install the network-manager package, too.

```
apt-get install network-manager
```

You can also check the status with:

```
systemctl status network-manager
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my experience, I have never seen Network Manager and a fully populated netplan yaml file work properly. I suspect that this will be no exception.

Comment: root@nextcloudserv:/etc/netplan# systemctl status network-manager
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor p
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-07-30 11:41:42 CEST; 50s ago
     Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
 Main PID: 4575 (NetworkManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
           └─4575 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Comment: does not work either :(

Comment: It is working for me, but probably because I have some other configuration files that I am overlooking.  I also have an /etc/NetworkManager.conf file that looks like this:

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[device-ens33]
match-device=interface-name:ens33
ignore-carrier=true
managed=true

[device-other]
match-device=type:ethernet
managed=false

I think the key here is to make sure your device is listed as "managed=true".